# Does the alternating series converge: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\left[\frac{8n+2}{7n+1}\right]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm trying to find out whether the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\left[\frac{8n+2}{7n+1}\right]$$ converges or not, but the alternating series test seems not to apply. What other tests can I use? Does this series converges or diverges?

Comment: The terms don't even tend to zero, so.....

Comment: @T.Bongers The term inside the floor function goes to $8/7$ which means that the limit will be $\ln 1 = 0$

Comment: @Ant How can that be possible? The limit is $\;\log\frac87\neq\log1=0\;$, isn't it?

Comment: @Joanpemo The square brackets used this way usually indicate the floor function.. If they are just parenthesis indeed you're correct

Comment: @Ant Those look like brackets to me, not $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$.

Comment: Those look to me as brackets, too...The floor function usually uses $\;\lfloor.\rfloor\;$, I think.

Comment: @T.Bongers Defintely, but sometimes I've seen square brackets used in place of $\lfloor \rfloor$. Anyhow I guess the OP is the only one who can settle the question :-)

Comment: yeah, those are usual brackets

Comment: Oh okay then! The answer by Joanpemo is good :)

Comment: @Ant You are right, the floor function can also use those parentheses, yet I'd expect the asker to be crystal clear about this.

Answer (score 4):

$$\log\frac{8n+2}{7n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\log\frac87\neq0$$

and thus

$$(-1)^n\log\frac{8n+2}{7n+1}\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies\text{ the series cannot converge}$$

Comment: you forgot the floor function

Comment: @Ant Thank you, but excuse me: what floor function? For me those are square parentheses...Perhaps the asker can clear this out.

Comment: @Ant Thank you. Yes, but it really can cause confusion.